# Are there inline functions in java?

Tags: java, inline-code

Is there a concept of inline functions in java, or its replaced something else? If there is, how is it used? I've heard that `public`, `static` and `final` methods are the inline functions. Can we create our own inline function?

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function, not http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function, right?

Comment: As a minor comment, premature optimization is the root of all evil. Without fully understanding the nature of public, static and final you can't really understand the impact inlining might have - and that is dependent on the JVM you're using. Be sure to first answer why you need to inline something: it's almost certain there are higher ROI optimizations you can do elsewhere.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7772864/632951

Answer (score 133):

In Java, the optimizations are usually done at the JVM level.  At runtime, the JVM perform some "complicated" analysis to determine which methods to inline.  It can be aggressive in inlining, and the Hotspot JVM actually can inline non-final methods.

The java compilers almost never inline any method call (the JVM does all of that at runtime).   They do inline compile time constants (e.g. final static primitive values).  But not methods.

For more resources:

1. [Article: The Java HotSpot Performance Engine: Method Inlining Example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/whitepaper-135217.html#method)
2. [Wiki: Inlining in OpenJDK](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/Inlining), not fully populated but contains links to useful discussions.

Answer (score 18):

No, there is no [inline function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) in java. Yes, you can use a public static method anywhere in the code when placed in a public class. The java compiler may do [inline expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) on a static or final method, but that is not guaranteed.

Typically such code optimizations are done by the compiler in combination with the JVM/JIT/HotSpot for code segments used very often. Also other optimization concepts like register declaration of parameters are not known in java.

Optimizations cannot be forced by declaration in java, but done by compiler and JIT. In many other languages these declarations are often only compiler hints (you can declare more register parameters than the processor has, the rest is ignored).

Declaring java methods static, final or private are also hints for the compiler. You should use it, but no garantees. Java performance is dynamic, not static. First call to a system is always slow because of class loading. Next calls are faster, but depending on memory and runtime the most common calls are optimized withinthe running system, so a server may become faster during runtime!

Comment: `final` make no impact on JIT inlining

Comment: +1, But how can we **test** whether the compiled version of a method is inlined?

Comment: @Pacerier But why should we test whether something is inlined?

Comment: @Pacerier with `-XX:+LogCompilation` I think

Answer (score 15):

Java does not provide a way to manually suggest that a method should be inlined. As @notnoop says in the comments, the inlining is typically done by the JVM at execution time.

Answer (score 5):

What you said above is correct. Sometimes final methods are created as inline, but there is no other way to explicitly create an inline function in java.

Comment: Final methods are not guaranteed to be inline.

Comment: On HotSpot, adding `final` doesn't even make any difference as to whether the method is inlined or not.

Comment: @Thomas - which is why I said "Sometimes final methods..."

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline do you have an authoritative source for that? As far as I know, final methods can be inlined without employing a type guard, which means that the modifier makes inlining the method more efficient than without the modifier. I know that Jikes RVM takes this into account when deciding whether to inline. Are you certain that HotSpot doesn't do something similiar?

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are methods could be called "inline" methods in java, but depending on the jvm. After compiling, if the method's machine code is less than 35 byte, it will be transferred to a inline method right away, if the method's machine code is less than 325 byte, it could be transferred into a inline method, depending on the jvm.

Comment: These are *default* values for Oracle's VM, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html

Answer (score 2):

Real life example:

```
public class Control {
    public static final long EXPIRED_ON = 1386082988202l;
    public static final boolean isExpired() {
        return (System.currentTimeMillis() > EXPIRED_ON);
    }
}
```

Then in other classes, I can exit if the code has expired.  If I reference the EXPIRED_ON variable from another class, the constant is inline to the byte code, making it very hard to track down all places in the code that checks the expiry date.  However, if the other classes invoke the isExpired() method, the actual method is called, meaning a hacker could replace the isExpired method with another which always returns false.

I agree it would be very nice to force a compiler to inline the static final method to all classes which reference it.  In that case, you need not even include the Control class, as it would not be needed at runtime.

From my research, this cannot be done.  Perhaps some Obfuscator tools can do this, or, you could modify your build process to edit sources before compile.

As for proving if the method from the control class is placed inline to another class during compile, try running the other class without the Control class in the classpath.

Answer (score 2):

so, it seems there arent, but you can use this workaround using guava or an equivalent Function class implementation, because that class is extremely simple, ex.:

```
    assert false : new com.google.common.base.Function<Void,String>(){
        @Override public String apply(Void input) {
            //your complex code go here
            return "weird message";
        }}.apply(null);
```

yes, this is dead code just to exemplify how to create a complex code block (within {}) to do something so specific that shouldnt bother us on creating any method for it, AKA inline!

Comment: Seems like a reasonable idea. Do you have a version of this that doesn't use the google common libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Java9 has an "Ahead of time" compiler that does several optimizations at compile-time, rather than runtime, which can be seen as inlining.

Answer (score 0):

YES, there are inline functions in Java.
You can write an inline function by using Functional Interfaces introduced at Java version 8.

Here is an example;

```java
// with a String parameter and a String return type 

Function<String, String> greet = name -> "Hello " + name;
```

Invocation;

```java
String result = greet.apply("Abdullah");

// result: Hello Abdullah
```

If your inline function doesn't need a parameter but only a return type, then you should use a Supplier.

```java
// with a String return type 

Supplier<String> greet = () -> "Hello S.O.";
```

Invocation;

```java
String result = greet.get("Abdullah");

// result: Hello Abdullah
```