# "Inlining" in Java

Tags: java, inline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there inline functions in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096361/are-there-inline-functions-in-java)

I come from C++, where I would write

```
for (int i = 0; i < numNonZero(); ++i)
```

knowing that numNonZero(), being very small and "inline" would simply vanish from the compiled code. How about in Java? Should I instead have an int _numNonZero in my class and write

```
for (int i = 0; i < _numNonZero; ++i)
```

for maximum speed?

Comment: What is meant by `being very small and "inline" would simply vanish from the compiled code.`? Vanish to where?

Comment: Are you asking whether or not the compiler will optimise out the method call? The answer to that is no, in both javac and gcc.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/2096361/484072

Comment: you have no control of inlining in Java it may be done at runtime by the JIT, also prefixing variable names with `_` in Java is not idiomatic Java and considered bad practice.

Comment: Lynks: that does not match my experience of looking at asm generated by gcc.

Comment: Adel: what I mean is that gcc can optimize numNonZero() to not generate a subroutine call in asm.

Answer (score 10):

Focus instead on writing the most readable code and let the [HotSpot Java virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) optimize this at runtime.

Answer (score 7):

It does not matter. Java code is converted to executable code at runtime by the java virtual machine. Hotspot or other modern jvms has very advance inlining capabilities. For maximum performance I could recommend you to use -server flag, which will perform aggressive optimizations.

Comment: Yep.  It's the JIT's job to decide where things like this can be inlined, not the programmer's.

Comment: The JIT doesn't always get it right.  I just discovered it won't inline methods over 35 bytecodes.  Manually doing this for one method in one loop of mine just saved me 15% cpu time.  I look forward to the day when the JIT would have realised that :)

Answer (score 5):

Like the others said, you should worry first and foremost about readable code.  However, to answer your question, although the compiler `javac` does no inlining, Hotspot--the JVM Optimizer--[will inline it for you](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Networking/HotSpot/inlining.html) if it can.

Comment: +1 for the better link, although mine offers the solace of noting that HotSpot is written in C++. :-)

Comment: Well, the other day I was working with "Iterator" in Java, and I got a 5X speed-up by replacing them with ints. I'm suspicious of Java's capabilities now...

Comment: @Frank The JIT moves in mysterious ways. ;)

Comment: @Frank: Fair enough, but `Integer` and `int` have different features. Java profilers are typically quite informative, allowing one to focus on the low-hanging fruit first..

Answer (score 3):

The `javac` does almost no optimisations. Instead the optimisation are performed at runtime. You can see if a method has been inlined at runtime with `-XX:+PrintCompilation`

Comment: The output of  `-XX:+PrintCompilation` output is not very well documented. I found this article [About PrintCompilation](https://gist.github.com/1165804#file_notes.md) very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Recommended by Joshua Bloch in for(;;){;} :

```
for (int i = 0, n = numNonZero() ; i < n; ++i) { ..
```

If numNonZero() change (and return a String.length(), or made some computation), you code remain correct.