# Mechanism in Java compiler to substitute method name as literal string

Tags: java

Is there a keyword (or equivalent) in Java that the compiler substitues with the name of the method (and/or class, etc) that the keyword appears in?  This would be similar to the

```
__FUNCTION__
```

macro is C/C++.

I know Java "doesn't support macros", but I'm not asking for user #define'able macros, just a small set of keywords that are replaced with literal strings that the compiler knows.

I know there are methods to get the method a piece of code appears in (http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0420.html) but I'm assuming these are not cost-free.  Not surprisingly, if this functionality exists I'd like to use it in tracing, so it really does need to have zero cost or very close to it.

I guess this would be up to the compiler implementation, so maybe my question is whether the usual Java compilers (whatever comes with the JDK) support this.

If not, I fail to understand why this isn't available since it seems useful and I assume it would be trivial for the compiler to provide since surely it knows the method name of the code it's compiling.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I don't think this is possible with Java 7.

Comment: Nope. That's the only way to get it--looking on the stack. Notice that it is a generic way to get the name of the current method or the one that called it or the one that called that and so forth.

Comment: Sure, it's trivial for the compiler to provide -- but it's also trivial for _you_ to provide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there inline functions in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096361/are-there-inline-functions-in-java)

Comment: @Louis - Do you mean it's trivial to inspect the stack at runtime, or that it is trivial to add a step to the build process?

Comment: @DavidStone: I mean it's trivial for you to write by hand when you're writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

In case of final method compiler may replace an invocation with the actual body of the method like Macro. This mechanism is called `inlining`.

In C++, we have option of declaring a function a `inline`.

Comment: I don't think it would be valid for the Java compiler to do this. It's normally part of the function of a JIT compiler.