# View Java functions inlined

Tags: java, user-interface, inline-code

First off all, I know there are several questions about "Java inline". But they are all about how the compiler or JVM inlines function calls. I'm interested in doing this myself, or create some kind of a View for it. I want to define a function call of a class, and want to see **everything** inlined. Every method call should get inlined. I'm not sure how to handle instantiation of new objects, but it doesn't matter as much.

The goal is manual optimization, i.e. if a parameter is checked too often against `null`. Is there a tool to to something like this? I would prefer a GUI, but some kind of command line tool where I can specify a class function and it dumps some text somewhere will suffice, too.

**EDIT**:

For clearification:

Today I argued to use the `NullObjectPattern`, because some are defensively overchecking for nulls everywhere. This makes the code unreadable and unclean. I dont like it and wanted to have some kind of a tool, to show them how often they are actually checking the very same parameter again and again for null.

Comment: This is not a good way to optimize code. Profiling is.

Comment: What are you asking? You are aware that the JVM is not the Java compiler right?

Comment: JVM inlines function calls... Does it?

Comment: As per this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2096388/994125), it is not possible to specify which method should be inlined. This is done by the JVM, not the compiler.

Comment: Eclipse, rightclick method, refactor, inline (or Alt+Shit+i) if you want to make your code unreadable manually.

Comment: @Antoniossss No. But the JIT might.

Comment: @zapl Ready! Fire! Take aim!

Comment: @zapl And unmaintainable.

Comment: I dont wanted to keep it inlined. As I had described, I just wanted to `View` it inlined

Answer (score 1):

As was said: Don't guess, especially when you don't know what the JIT compiler will do after the code has been running for a while. You can waste infinite time infinitely improving something that accounts for 1% of runtime and only save 1%, or you can spend a short time getting a 10% improvement of something that accounts for 20% of your runtime and save 2%; the latter is by far a better choice.

The way you determine what's worth improving is by properly profiling your code after it has been fully warmed up.

And the way you get a significant improvement generally has more to do with improved algorithms than with microtuning of single instructions.